# Looking for a better way to get random items (One that allows for more options)

Tags: java, android, random

At the minute i am using a lot of functions like this in my android app.

```java
public String class5e() {
    String[] data = {
            "barbarian",
            "bard",
            "cleric",
            "druid",
            "fighter",
            "monk",
            "paladin",
            "ranger",
            "rogue",
            "sorcerer",
            "warlock",
            "wizard"
    };
    return data[randInt(0, data.length)];
}
```

This is great for most of my app but at ti es i need to do more, say for example i want to have it make add to a database of wizards every time the wizard option is selected, well i could make a wizzard function that returns wizard as a string and does all the data base entrys etc so that if wizard is picked it does what needs to be done....only that doesnt work, if i do that then the wizard code is setup when the array is processed regardless of the option picked.

I could use switch and case but you then have to hardcode the number of cases there are so no chance of Dding to the list dynamicly (a long term goal of mine) plus it introduces a lot of extra text to each option. Same issue with if statements.

So is there a way to randomly choose from a list of options and execute code as needed if certain options are chosen, simply and efficently?

Comment: I think that the answer is in the question "...if certain options are chosen...", otherwise a revised architecture of code might be needed.

Comment: Sure, instead of using strings, use enums or class instances that have relevant functionality. Basically the command or action pattern.

Comment: Revised structure is most likely needed yes but not sure what to, still new to java (well newish) i nestle a lot of functions to, for example if a colour is needed i call a function that returns a colour as a string added to the string "wizard "+ colour() not sure that  can be done with enum lists (those are new to me so will be reading up on them in a sec)

Comment: It has crossed my mind that i can see if wizard is chosen and then do the extra stuff, just examing the string will tell me that,  ut with so much of java still unknown to me i was thinki g there may be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options

Let me list out what I know

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] data = {
            "barbarian",
            "bard",
            "cleric",
            "druid",
            "fighter",
            "monk",
            "paladin",
            "ranger",
            "rogue",
            "sorcerer",
            "warlock",
            "wizard"
        };
        //Option 1
        Random random = new Random();
        String strRandom = data[random.nextInt(data.length)];
        System.out.println("item [1]: "+ strRandom);
        //Option 2
        strRandom = data[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(data.length)];
        System.out.println("item [2]: "+ strRandom);
        //Option 3
        strRandom = data[(int)(Math.random()*data.length)];
        System.out.println("item [3]: "+ strRandom);
    }
}
```

Check my experiment as well : http://rextester.com/KTD88460

**Edit after comment**

If you are looking for something dynamically growing, use `ArrayList` or have a look at the [Collection Framework](http://manojprasaddevelopers.blogspot.in/2012/02/java-collections-framework.html) to choose one.

Comment: Getting the random number is not  the issue, sorry for the confusion there, its more the best way to store what i am randomly choosing from, i wish i was better at wording things...which i supose is part of the issue, at the minute im using string arrays, i found switch to be somewhat unyeldy no way to expand later (no way to load a list of user submitted professions and add them to the options unless you know the exact number) ...arrays how ever dont allow me to do much more with the code then spit out a string